# How could somebody become more resistant to electricity while still appearing to be a normal human

Tags: electricity, cybernetics

In my story characters get powers through implants for example people who control magnetism getting electromagnets as implants and people who control life getting nanotech that can morph into different shapes.

I have one character (main protagonist) that can control electricity. I have already figured out the electrical generation process and where the implant should go but I need to find how the character would be made resistant to electricity. Like surviving a lightning bolt with minor injuries and not even feeling a taser.

Also just to clarify I think that the implant should be a lightning rod but I am unsure about how to ground the body.

The characters in my story appear to be human and having a massive metal box surrounding you at all times would not look human at all. Lastly assume this world has a current tech level besides dealing with the logistics of cybernetic implants.

So how could somebody become immune to electricity with cybernetic implants while still appearing to be human?

Comment: A high enough level of electricity can turn solid matter into plasma, so the question becomes how *much* electricity do you want them to be *resistant* to? There's a big difference between shrugging off a Taser and biting into a multi-gigawatt high-voltage line.

Comment: What I meant was how could this character become more resistant to electricity. Like withstanding a taser up to withstanding a lightning bolt with only minor injuries. Like animals can become resistant to fire with aerogel but that doesn’t mean you can throw them into a nuclear bomb and survive

Comment: Also just to clarify I have an idea which is making the skin much more resistive. While having a lightning rod on the spinal cord that would carry away electric energy to the soles of the feet which would be made conductive to ground the body. But I’m not an electrical engineer so I don’t now if this is correct.

Comment: The problem at certain levels of power isn't heart attacks or brain damage; it's your tissues vaporizing. I'm not sure how to get around said heart attacks/brain damage but I do know there is a hard upper limit for any creature whose body includes flesh.

Comment: ''Look! It's Down-To-Earth-Man!'' - Sorry, I had to make that Pun.

Comment: It’s okay that’s actually funny

Comment: @KEY_ABRADE You're not wrong, but there's lots of flexibility. The higher the frequency, the more electricity simply skitters along the surface of the skin. Get high enough and it moves through skin oil (not skin). Get higher than that (like, microwave...) and the oil boils... then ignites. But physics ain't the goal here - suspension of disbelief is. So I'm not particularly worried about levels unless our intrepid hero is embracing the lightning strike. I think there's more than enough wiggle room to come up with a couple of cool explanations/rationalizations.

Comment: Rubber feet? ;) on a more serious note, perhaps look into how electric eels do it? they appear to be a normal eel to me so whatever their method for not getting shocked by their own electrical click is it can't be too necessitating of major morphological change.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use a lightning rod**

You're right, how on earth does one ground a body? Yes, there are wristbands that clip to grounded lines to keep humans from affecting electronics with ESD, but it really doesn't work.

*Let's try this in the other direction.*

1. I watched a college physics professor hold a fluorescent bulb in each hand and stand away from a high voltage generator. He pointed one bulb at the generator and the other at the opposite wall. They both lit up. Why? Electricity takes the shortest path to ground and the *resistance of his body* was greater than the *resistance of the air gap between the second bulb and ground.* It didn't hurt that the high voltage electricity was also high frequency, which ran along the surface of his skin rather than penetrating into the body.
2. I've heard of electricians who <s>are stupid enough to</s> touch live AC wires with little effect because their skin is so dry the resistance is sky-high, so the electricity doesn't penetrate the body.

My point? *Increase the resistance of the body.* You don't want to suck electricity in and then wonder what to do with it, don't let it penetrate in the first place. You could be mean to your character and make his skin dry as a bone. But you could also impregnate his skin and muscle tissue with insoluble carbon molecules. Diamond would work. Graphite is electrically conductive, but diamond is a semiconductor that would raise the resistance of the flesh.

A better solution would be to come up with your own technobabble (unobtainium...) to describe a fictional substance that's not toxic to the body, is flexible such that it doesn't tear up the body when the body is in use, and yet raises resistance.

Oh, and plan on using [Anticholinergic drugs](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9674821/) to keep our hero from sweating. Sweat (salt water) + electricity = bad.

Comment: Oh and btw would having an organ that emits a gas more resistive than air work. I think this because the electricity would not want to go through the gas with the higher resistance compared to the air with the lower resistance.

Comment: @Ilikelightning When you say "work," keep in mind that what you really mean is "could people suspend their disbelief." We're not looking for a solution that would "actually work." There wouldn't be any fiction if we did that. Having said that... the gas would explain a barrier between the body and open air, which would make sense if the electricity being manipulated is not touching the body anywhere.

Comment: @Ilikelightning can heroes exist forever surrounded by a wafting fart-bubble? :) Air is already pretty resistive, not much you can do to improve that. Very dry skin sounds good, maybe a metal staff to complement that? And an umbrella, wouldn't want pesky water to rain (sic) on your parade. Might also want to look into getting your supe few, but very sensitve, hair follicles to sus out incoming charge

Comment: @bukwyrm Actually, if the goal is to protect the body, then creating a less resistive path to ground through the air is an option the OP could take. It would be a tricky balance to ensure your vicious attack doesn't just make a pretty glass sculpture in the dirt - but that's what being a super hero is all about, right? However, the (chuckle) "wafting fart-bubble" would be a good rationalization for keeping the rain off the super hero.